# How to getElement of radio button embedded in <div>

Tags: html, selenium, web-scraping, browser

```
<div data-v-7868f2da="" data-v-a71d9b0a="" role="radio" aria-checked="false" aria-label="No" additionalarialabel="No"
    class="radio-button-container" tabindex="0" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;">
    <div data-v-7868f2da="" class="inactive-radio-button border-color-undefined"></div>
</div>
```

Above is the element in question. I can't seem to be able to get this element with Selenium?

I've tried just getting the Xpath (both relative and absolute) with F12, but that does not seem to work.

I have tried the other options provided if I right-click on the radio button when F12 on Chrome.

I would really appreciate any suggestions

Comment: Post the URL to debug.

Comment: Sorry, but this post needs some context, and clarification.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `document.querySelectorAll()` by querying the role name
For example `document.querySelectorAll('[role="radio"]')`

NOTE: This will get all elements with that role name if you want a specific button I guess you have to prefix the div with an id.